# MeteorJS Package : Accessing "events" and "helpers" of a Template inside a package (internally)

Tags: events, meteor, package

I created a local package and added to my project, and added templating.

**package.js**

```
`Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.4.2.3');
  api.use('templating', 'client');
  api.addFiles('server/main.js', 'server');
  api.addFiles('client/main.js', 'client');
  api.addFiles('client/main.html', 'client');
  api.mainModule('pkgName.js');
});`
```

I created a template in **client/main.html**.

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <button>Test</button>
</template>
```

Then in **client/main.js**, i set the event listener:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click button': function (e,t){ //do this on click };
})
```

But when i run the app - **i get console error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - after a couple of hours of research it seems that the Package.onUse function must list dependencies in the order that they should be loaded.

I thought the load order was only relevant to the 'packages' file in the main application, but it seems that you need to load the dependencies in order as well.

So this fixed it---

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.4.2.3');
  api.addFiles('client/main.html', 'client');  

// I moved the html file above the javascript - so the DOM loads first and then the template exists for the event listener to listen to. 

  api.use('templating', 'client');
  api.addFiles('server/main.js', 'server');
  api.addFiles('client/main.js', 'client');
  api.mainModule('pkgName.js');
});
```